The ignoreDuplicates option on bulkCreate on Sequelize returns the data that was attempted to be created
I'm working on a node.js project using Sequelize as the orm, and postgres as the database engine, we're evaluating a concurrency solution for an endpont. This endpoint, among other things, first checks the existing rows for a table named Package, then calls some endpoints to get data for the new rows, then does a bulkCreate for the new ones, and then returns both the existing and the new packages.
When 2 requests access one endpoint at the same time, the bulkCreate could be executed twice for the same data (for some or all rows), failing because of unique constraints. And this is actually happening right now for some clients, that for some reason call the endpoint multiple times for the same data.
The solution I thought of was using the ignoreDuplicates option, like this:
const newPackages = await models.Package.bulkCreate(
  packagesData,
  { ignoreDuplicates: true }
)

But the problem is that, when duplicated, it returns the same data I tried to insert.
Is there a way to make bulkCreate return either:

only the rows that were actually created,
or the duplicated rows with the actual data in the database?

If there's no way to do this, the only solution would be to do a select query right after the bulkCreate, right?
But we're avoiding doing more stuff in this endpoint, which already takes a lot of time. So, ideally, I would prefer to do this select query only when there's a concurrency issue, so this doesn't impact the rest of the requests, since this happens only for some clients. But this would mean doing something like this:
try {
  const newPackages = await models.Package.bulkCreate(
    packagesData,
    { ignoreDuplicates: true }
  )
} catch (error) {
  if (error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
    // select to get existing queries, add them to the existing to be returned
    // bulkCreate on the rest
  }
}

But that other bulkCreate could also fail, so I would have to wrap it in a while loop maybe, and repeat until success, but this could lead to timeouts. I could avoid doing that second bulkCreate if there's a way to make the bulkCreate fail, but still insert the unproblematic rows.
But if there's no other way, I'll have to do a select for all requests. That would mean using ignoreDuplicates on bulkCreate, and then doing the select to "correct" that data.
What do you think is the best solution?
